# How to avoid this overlapping in plain CSS?

Tags: css

Hellou, I am very new to all this HTML, CSS, made some web page but don't know what's happenning here. I want to make this skills appear on second line when comes to the end of first. Width is 700 and all is positioned to center, and I don't know why is overlapping. Thanks

[image: This is a ul list with li items]

Values connected with skills class:

```
 .projects, .badges, .links, .skills {
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.projects ul, .badges ul, .links ul, .skills ul {
list-style-type: none;
}

.projects li, .badges li, .links li, .skills li {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

.skills {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.skills li{
font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
background-color: #444;
color: #ccc;
font-weight: bold;
display:inline;
padding: 8px;
margin-right: 10px;

}
```

Comment: share your HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `display:inline` that causes this issue because the line-height is not properly defined, so doesn't matters the padding or the margin. Turn it to inline-block and it works with margins, paddings, and all you need

```
.skills li{ 
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

This works

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
li {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

because if you use `display: inline`, the padding and margin overlap with other div or tags. The inline-block take as the `li` as block element.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using listitems for this. Try this:

```
<div class="the_box_where_your_skills_are_in">
    <a class="skillitem">CSS/HTML</a>
</div>
```

And CSS quite simple, just a width to the box with your Skills and the a-tags will have some padding, margin, background and `display: block, float: left`

Comment: That is too advanced, I started to learn few days ago.
Solution below helps.

Comment: If you never try, you will never become better ;)

Comment: And why you don't recommend list items?

Comment: Because they are a lot more complicated in my opinion and they act the sane as simple a-tags

Answer (score 1):

You can also get result like

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="float:left;" class="content">Windows</div>
<div style="float:left;" class="content">Linux</div>
<div style="float:left;" class="content">Basic  </div>
<div style="float:left;" class="content">Software</div>
<div style="float:left;" class="content">Hardware</div>
<div style="float:left;" class="content">Networking</div>
<div style="float:left;" class="content">PHP</div>
</div>
```

CSS :-

```
div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content {
    width:100px;
}

#wrapper {
    min-width: 300px; /* 100px x3 = 300 */
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

[Demo] :- http://jsfiddle.net/5zsyj/200/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/5zsyj/200/)